# for vs in in a preposition after the verb "travel"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I wonder which is the correct preposition to be taken after the verb `travel`, to express the travel for/in a country.

> I plan to travel for China.
>
> I plan to travel in China.

Which is the correct preposition? And when to use `in` and when to use `for` in a preposition after the verb `travel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases, as a learner, I suggest that you check the Oxford dictionary. It always provides many nice examples through which you can discover the idiomatic sentences and collocations. By the way, the idiomatic preposition is **[to](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/travel)**.

You can say

> I plan to travel **to** China

In terms of your second question. You can use those prepositions in different context. For instance, you can say:

> - It's really interesting to travel in groups.
> - It's really easy to travel in the USA.
>
> (Using "in" when talking about the place itself like USA, Canada,...
>   and when describing the way of traveling)

Or

> - I traveled for a month.
> - I traveled for a business goal.
>
> (Using "for" when talking about reason or duration)

By the way, our native friend on ELL can provide you with more accurate and idiomatic examples. I thought It's a good idea to mention some myself.

Comment: Thanks. But isn't it that the Oxford is for British English? I prefer American English. I shall note it in my question, though.

Comment: @Blaszard Yes, but it declares that issue in case there is discrepancy. Or if the difference is really significant.